# Removing a user account in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I just installed Windows 8 Pro on my PC, and I accidentally made two user accounts, one local and one connected online. I want to remove the local one, but I don't know how to do it. I searched the "change PC settings" panel, but I found nothing there. Where I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command Prompt > lusrmgr.msc opens user management mmc. Right-click to delete the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel > More Settings > Add or remove user accounts > Select the local user > Click "Delete the account"
([source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhu3VTCHTUQ))

Answer (score 0):

you want to delete the profile
right click on my pc
advanced
User profiles -> Settings
select the profile  -> Delete -> ok-> ok-> ok-> ok

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with removed user's directory still existing under `C:\users`.
I tried to take ownership - worked for all files except a couple.

Used a utility called LockHunter to see "What's locking this file?" and well - it was the the service `WMPNetworkSvc`. (I had logged on one time on the removed user account.)

Closed down the service and... the directory disappeared!

Maybe this would have been resolved anyway after a restart.

Answer (score -1):

You should check it the account is really gone by verifying that the directory of the account name is removed from c:\Users. I deleted two local accounts and still cannot get rid of the directories. Even as administrator you are denied access even with UAC off.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  All you need to do is take ownership of the directory.