# System defaults to logging into deleted Local account

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, login

I followed a brief tutorial about how to migrate my Windows 8 installation from one Live account to the other.  The tutorial said you switch from the first Live account to a local account.  And from that local account, you log into your new live account.  I did this without any problems.

My issue is that whenever I restart my Computer, it defaults to asking me for credentials for my 'Local' account.  There are two images of 'keys' under the input areas where I can select my Live account and log in that way, or stay with the local, which appears to be the systems new default way to attempt to log me in.

I have checked in my Control Panel at `Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts\Manage Accounts`, and I get the option to modify my Live account, or the Guest account, which is turned off.  Not the Local account.

I also followed the instructions from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/499129/removing-a-user-account-in-windows-8-pro) saying to run `lusrmgr.msc` in a `cmd`. I checked my listings there, and nothing seemed available for deletion.  The options I get from this window are:

- Administrator
- Guest
- HomegroupUser$
- Mcx1-Rob - Media Center Extender
- stat30fbliss - My current logged in account
- UpdatusUser - Used to provide Nvidia Software Updates

I tried deleting `stat30fbliss` but it said it was my current logged-in account, so I cancelled.